GCC Ld : what are the mandatories sections?
Looking at different linker scripts, they do not always define the same memory sections.
Some contain for example .sbss, .sdata, and some do not. Some contain sections that are not found anywhere else, etc.
So I am wondering: which sections are mandatories in a linker script ?
I guess that at least .text and .data are required, but what about the others ?
Let's suppose I do not declare a .bss section nor a .rodata section, what can happen in this case ? Or if I do not define a .stack and a .heap, how does the compiler handle that ?

You can read about this in the ELF specification for Linux or the PE specification for Windows.
